# EXM campaign stuck - The contact list 'XXX' is locked by another process

Tags: exm

I'm using CM and Email dispatcher to send emails. A campaign is about to finish, but the dispatchsummary.aspx on my ED server is showing a running job with no actual emails sent.

Now this unfinished campaign is effectively blocking the ED from sending more campaigns.

From the exm.log:

> 6100 10:52:52 ERROR Failed to remove contact '{83CC5E55-73EE-488B-9971-43089D4BDC48}' from include list(s)
>   Exception: Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.RecipientCollections.OperationTimeoutException
>   Message: The contact list 'XXX' is locked by another process. The operation could not be completed within the timeout interval 00:00:20.
>   Source: Sitecore.EmailCampaign
>      at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.ListManager.ContactList.InvokeOperationWithRetry(TimeSpan timeout, TimeSpan retryInterval, Func`1 operation)
>      at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.ListManager.ContactList.RemoveRecipient(RecipientId recipientId, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.SubscriptionManager.RemoveUserFromList(RecipientId recipientId, ID listId)
>      at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Pipelines.SpamComplaintAndBounce.RemoveFromIncludeList.Process(HandleMessageEventPipelineArgs args)

How can I make the campaign finish so that the ED resumes sending again?

Comment: By email dispatcher, do you mean a dedicated dispatch server i.e. a secondary CM with the email processing package installed? Have any emails been sent? Are there any errors in the EDS log? Are you using the Custom SMTP or Dyn provider?

The error in the log file is related to bounce/spam complaint processing and does not affect dispatches.

Comment: It might be a contact list that is stuck. check the recipient contact list in List Manager and see if it's locked. if so, unlock it.

Comment: Yes, unlocking the list and recycling app pool eventually helped. Isn't it a bit ridiculous to make my client monitor email dispatching in the middle of the night and manually solve this issue while it should be fully automated?:/

Comment: Yeah, see my question on exactly this. http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/230/is-there-anyway-to-improve-the-speed-that-list-manager-builds-a-list

Comment: Something is not adding up here. 

The dispatch process is divided up into several pipeline processors, one of these being the QueueMessage processor which requires the recipient lists. The remaining pipeline processors, including the actual dispatch one (SendMessage), do not require the lists.

If the campaign is about to finish, I assume it's past the queueing state? If so, the exception or the list being locked should not be an issue.

If the campaign is dispatching, problems can occur if contacts are locked. In this case however those contacts will simply be skipped.

Comment: I'm going to put this on hold until the author can provide the details necessary to offer a proper answer. kozziification, If you can add that information, feel free to 'flag; this post to be re-opened. Thank you.